# How can I define comparison has to be an int?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, int

Here a short code for the thing which is already coded:

```
if (str.Length % 3 != 0)
```

Now my question is, how can I define, that if `str.Length % 3 = int` it has to do something?

Here an example:

`123456789123 / 3 = int...`

I know, the Syntax I used isn't correct, but it's because I don't know how to do it.
You would also help me, if you told me, what the "opposite" of  `if (str.Length % 3 != 0)` is.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Since `.Length` returns `int`, I don't see anything wrong in your code. And % has higher predence then != operator. What is the actual problem you get? Are you try to use your `str` not `str.Lenght`? Because I don't think your `str.Length` is `123456789123` I assume it is a string `:)`

Comment: Opposite of str.Length%3!=0 is str.Length%3==0

Comment: @anonymous Surely the opposite is !(str.Length%3!=0)

Comment: @SonerGönül, maybe the OP wants to determine if the result is a float or int type? In other words, if there will be some remainder or not... Simple negation of the current statement will probably do just fine.

Comment: @SamHolder that is also possible. But I was thinking along the lines of nonzero and zero. So opposite of nonzero is zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be an `int` no matter what with the code you have provided.

Reason: `int / int = int` ... any decimal values will be truncated (not rounded). C# does not automatically turn numbers into `float` or `double` if there is need for it. You need to do type conversion of that nature explicitly.

I think you may have also confused modulo `%` and divide `/`. If you want to know if there is no remainder which means that the number coming out of the computation is an Integer do the `if (str.Length % 3 != 0)` you put in the code.... I assume you're looking for something like this

```
if (str.Length % 3 != 0)
{
    int num = str.Length / 3;
    //Now do something with your int version of num
}
else
{
    double num = str.Length / (double)3;
    //Now do something with your double version of num
}
```

By casting 3 which is an `int` to `double` the resulting number will be a `double`, if you don't do that you will get a truncated integer value then implicitly casted to a `double` and stored in `num`.

Answer (score 1):

The statement `str.Length % 3` always results in an integer. What you need is probably just a simple negation of this statement, that will tell you, that there is a remainder...

Negation of `!=` is of course `==`

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
if ((str.Length % 3).GetType() == typeof(int))
{
        //is integer
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me a situation when the result of `str.Length % 3` won't be of type `integer`?

Comment: Your answer is meaningless. `int % int` is always returns `int`.